# Website freezes when adding qrcodes in for loop

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am using a QRcode-generator plugin which somehow freezes the browser when creating QRcodes in a for loop. This is weird because I followed the documentation/tutorial on the git repo (link further down).

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.qrcode.min.js"></script>
<div id="qrcode" style="display: none;"></div>
```

**After AJAX success:**

*overall_result* is following json:

> {"error": false,"error_msg":"","result":["item1","item2","item3"]}

```
var overall_result = JSON.parse(response);
var result = overall_result.result;

for(var f = 0; f < result.length; f++){
    jQuery('#qrcode').qrcode("this plugin is great");
}
```

**If I loop through an already created array it works:**

```
var array = ["test", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test", "test1", "test2", "test3"]

for(var f = 0; f < array.length; f++){
        jQuery('#qrcode').qrcode("this plugin is great");
    }
```

I have come to sort of a conclusion. Everytime when i create a QRcode inside a function it seems to not work, not even with onclick. It works if the script is just in the plain html script-tag.

Note: The AJAX request executes after onclick.

Plugin i use:
[jquery.qrcode.min.js](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/jquery-qrcode)

Comment: If you do just one without the loop, does it work? It sounds like you're simply trying to do too many at once.

Comment: @TylerRoper The problem is not the loop, I will edit and show you why.

Comment: What happens if you do `jQuery('#qrcode').html('')` before you create a new qrcode?

Comment: @charlietfl It looks like that plugin *adds* a QR code to the element. So by repeatedly calling it on the same item, it would add multiple QR codes to one single container named `qrcode`. Hard to say though, I'm just going by this *"Then you add the qrcode in this container by `jquery('#qrcode').qrcode("this plugin is great");`"*

Comment: Without seeing what the *actual* array looks like, the fact that one is created and one is not doesn't really help us unfortunately. What is `result.length`? Maybe the one you're creating manually works because it has just a handful of items, whereas `result` has hundreds or more. The bottom line is that we're going to need more context/code to help you out here, otherwise we're simply guessing.

Comment: @AlonEitan It still freezes, but I want to store the QRcode for later use anyways.

Comment: @EliasKnudsen Can you replace the loop with `console.log(result.length)` and tell us what it returns?

Comment: @TylerRoper never would have expected it but you are right, it keeps appending http://plnkr.co/edit/tGdef7AxYDQuOz61eBo3?p=preview